# Spring validating a object before returning it in a function not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a service, that gets an xml/json string, tries to read it as an pojo, then returns it. Then, I want to show the result in thymeleaf. I did that successfully, but - in the model I have validation annotations, but if I submit invalid information it accepts the value, although I validated the method. Here is my code:
Controller:

```
@Controller
public class ConvertController implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Autowired
PrintJSON printJSON;
@Autowired
PrintXML printXML;
@Autowired
ReadJSON readJSON;
@Autowired
ReadXML readXML;
@GetMapping("/read")
public String showReadForm() {
    return "read";
}
@PostMapping("/read")
public String read(@RequestParam(value = "convertFrom") String 
convertFrom, String text, Model model){
    if("json".equals(convertFrom)){
        Book newBook = readJSON.read(text);
        model.addAttribute("result", newBook);
        return "converted";
    }else if("xml".equals(convertFrom)){
        Book newBook = readXML.read(text);
        model.addAttribute("result", newBook);
        return "converted";
    }
    return "read";

}
@GetMapping("/print")
public String showPrintForm(Book book){
    return "convert";
}
@PostMapping("/print")
public String convert(@RequestParam(value = "convertTo") String 
convertTo, @Valid Book book, Errors errors, Model model) {
    if(errors.hasErrors()){
        return "convert";
    }
    if("json".equals(convertTo)){
        model.addAttribute("result", printJSON.getJSON(book));
        return "converted";
    }
    if("xml".equals(convertTo)){
        model.addAttribute("result", printXML.getXML(book));
        return "converted";
    }
    return "convert";

}}
```

Service

```
public class ReadXML {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("XmlMapper")
XmlMapper xmlMapper;

@Valid
public Book read(String xml){
    try{
        @Valid Book book = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, Book.class);
        return book;
    }
    catch(JsonProcessingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new Book();
    }



}
}
```

Model

```
public class Book {
@NotEmpty
private String title;
private String description;
private Date publishDate;
private int ISBN;
private List<@Valid Author> authors;
@Override
public String toString(){
    String bookString = String.format("Title: %s\nDescription: %s\nPublish Date: %s\nISBN: %s\nAuthor", title, description, publishDate, ISBN);
    for(Author a : authors){
        bookString += a.toString();
    }
    return bookString;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description){
    this.description = description;
}
public Date getPublishDate() {
    return publishDate;
}
public void setPublishDate(String newPublishDate) throws ParseException {
    Date publishDate = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.dateFormat).parse(newPublishDate);
    this.publishDate = publishDate;
}
public int getISBN() {
    return ISBN;
}
public void setISBN(int ISBN){
    this.ISBN = ISBN;
}
public void addAuthor(Author author) {
    authors.add(author);
}
public List<Author> getAuthors(){
    return authors;
}
}
```

Where is my problem???
Thank you!

Comment: Have you added @Valid annotation in the controller? The controller code is not fully-added to your question.

Comment: I added the whole controller. The convert method is working, but the read one isn't. I didn't add @Valid there because model.Addatribute doesn't allows me, but ReadJSON and ReadXML have @ Valid, so they must return only valid values, if I am not wrong, but if I submit wrong values it returns them.

Comment: You really like to make things complex? You basically reinvented (in a crappy way, content negotiation). That being said you added `@Valid` but not the `@RequestBody`. However I would really urge you to take a look at what Spring can do for you and cleanup your code, instead of reinventing something that has been invented already.